# Using MOQ to get a property fails with Unsupported Expression (Non-overridable members)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have a line of code like this:

```
 foo = _testOutputService.SelectedPoint.PointType;
```

My test tries to get the firt parameter like this:

```
mockTestOutputService.Setup(x => x.SelectedPoint).Returns(mockSelectedPoint.Object);
```

but I get **Unsupported expression x=>x.SelectedPoint Non-overridable members**.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: The error would mean that `SelectedPoint` is not a virtual method on `TestOutputService` you should be mocking that class interface or make the methods virtual on the concrete class.

Comment: As mentioned in a previous comment, that error is usually associated with trying to setup a non virtual (overridable) member. Can you show the definition of the members shown in your post?